# Reference needed for Iron-based superconductors

Tags: condensed-matter, resource-recommendations, superconductivity

Iron-based superconductor is a class of high-$T_c$ superconductors discovered in 2008.

Are there any review papers about these superconductors yet? If not, which are the key papers in the field?

Answer (score 4):

Well, [Let Me Google That For You](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=iron%20based%20superconductor%20review%20articles)

For specific recommendations, the review in Nature by [Paglione and Greene](https://doi.org/10.1038/nphys1759)<sup>1</sup> is very highly cited and accessible.  There is a review of the magnetic properties [by Lumsden and Christianson](https://doi.org/10.1088/0953-8984/22/20/203203)<sup>2</sup> and a somewhat older article is available from [Hosono and collaborators](https://doi.org/10.1143/JPSJ.78.062001)<sup>3</sup>.   A Nature review on the debate over the pairing mechanism is available from [Mazin](https://doi.org/10.1038/nature08914)<sup>4</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup> J. Paglione & R. L. Greene, "High-temperature superconductivity in iron-based materials", *Nat. Phys.* **6**, 645-658 (2010), [arXiv:1006.4618](https://arxiv.org/abs/1006.4618).

<sup>2</sup> M. D. Lumsden & A. D. Christianson, "Magnetism in Fe-based superconductors", *J. Phys.: Condens. Matter* **22** 203203 (2010), [arXiv:1004.1969](https://arxiv.org/abs/1004.1969).

<sup>3</sup> K. Ishida, Y. Nakai, and H. Hosono, "To What Extent Iron-Pnictide New Superconductors Have Been Clarified: A Progress Report", *J. Phys. Soc. Jpn.* **78** (2009) 062001.

<sup>4</sup> I. I. Mazin, "Superconductivity gets an iron boost", *Nature* **464**, 183–186 (2010).

Answer (score 0):

[10.1103/RevModPhys.83.1589](https://doi.org/10.1103/RevModPhys.83.1589): A comprehensive review in Dec 2011 by G. R. Stewart containing a myriad of key experimental and theoretical results. Preprint available  at [arXiv:1106.1618](https://arxiv.org/abs/1106.1618).